# What is the meaning of "custom program error: 0x1771" erro?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-lang, anchor-test

what is the meaning of `custom program error: 0x1771` error? [image]

Answer (score 1):

`0x1771` translates to `6001` in decimal. Anchor appears to start its error codes at `6000`, so this would be the second error in the program.  If you look at the IDL for the invoked program, you should be able to see what code `6001` corresponds to.

Here's an example IDL from the Anchor repo, which gives the error codes for a sample program: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/6716c13b38ba8d2ddabbce071d50bc04b1b84483/tests/idl/idls/parse.json#L739